# Need drivers for a Dell v525w printer

Tags: printing, dell

I have a Dell Dimension 4700, still works fine and I don't want to buy another computer just to avoid the Windows XP shutdown.  Loaded Ubuntu 13.04, works great, but when I try to add my printer, my v525w is not one that is shown.  Contacted Dell and they only have windows drivers.  Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the generic driver: **Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5c**.

- Tested on **Ubuntu 12.04**

Others have reported that the same driver works on:

- **Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome** with the **DELL Color MFP E525w** printer

*You can change the driver for a printer like this:*

- Open "Printers"
- Click on your printer, e.g. **DELL MFP 525W**
- Click on the currently selected "**Model**"
- Select **Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5c**